# Find the average distance from a point $P(x,y)$ in the disk.

Tags: multiple-integral

I am solving the problem as follows:

"Find the average distance from a point $P(x,y)$ in the disk $x^2+y^2\le a^2$ to the origin."

The radius of the disk is $a$ and the area of the disk is $a^2\pi$.

The function describing the distance between the point in the disc and the origin would be

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}$$

Then we can convert the distance formula into polar form

$$g(r,\theta)=\sqrt{r^2}=r$$

Then the average distance is

$$\frac{1}{a^2\pi}\iint\limits_{R}g(r,\theta)rdrd\theta=\frac{1}{a^2\pi}\iint\limits_{R}r^2drd\theta$$

Now consider the limits.

$$0\le x^2+y^2\le a^2\implies 0\le r\le a$$

But I am not sure about the limits of $\theta$.

Should it be

$$0\le\theta\le\pi$$

Or $$0\le\theta\le 2\pi?$$

Comment: You are integrating over all the points in the disk, so you should consider $\theta$ to span the whole circle, $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.